# Why does the "About Us" link to about "Stack Overflow"?

Tags: discussion, tour

Consider:

[image]

I understand that the "About Us" can't be different for each Stack Exchange site, but would it make sense to link to something about Stack Exchange, rather than Stack Overflow?

Linking to Stack Overflow seems like your saying the Stack Overflow community is the same as the [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) community. Whereas a link to a generic "about Stack Exchange" would make sense to give people a broader picture of what Stack Exchange is about.

This is my thought process:

> I'm here to learn about English. But here's a link to a programming website that doesn't answer any of my questions and seems to be unrelated. This is weird. I thought I was at Stack Exchange. Is this another Stack Exchange site? It's a different domain. Why would a site about English link me to a site about programming in its about us?

Comment: You seem to want "About Us" to do what "Tour" does.

Comment: Did you miss the "Learn more about Sack Overflow the company" that is part of what you highlighted? Is that really so unclear?

Comment: StackOverflow is the brand name.

Comment: No. I'm asking about *why* SO is mentioned at all.

Comment: Stack Overflow is the brand for Stack Overflow. Stack Exchange is the brand for Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Oded as I also mention in my answer, there is a similar [about page](http://stackexchange.com/about) in stackexchange.com portal - why not linking to it?

Comment: @DavidPostill - almost - you are missing a space between "Stack" and "Overflow" ;)

Comment: @Matt I think what Oded is trying to say is that it's about Stack Overflow **the company**, not Stack Overflow the site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ah, OK. That makes sense. I question its place in a help section, then. The mention of Stack Overflow seems out of left field. There is no obvious link between Stack Overflow and EL&U on the page. Having an About Us that isn't related to the website you're on is jarring.

Comment: Like both answers and some comments here are saying, Stack Overflow **is** Stack Exchange, as far as names go (meaning the single term "Stack Overflow" got two different meanings: one is what we all know, the site itself, and one, which only few know, means the whole network of sites). It's confusing, true, but that is just how it is.

Comment: That's cool. It shouldn't be in the "help" section then, as it isn't going to help anyone. Its title, "About us", implies the site you are on (e.g. EL&U), or the network it is part of (i.e. Stack Exchange), but its subtitle conflicts with that and then the link takes the user somewhere else entirely. "About the creators" or something to indicate that you're leaving EL&U would be a start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As of February 2022](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415962/1478931), company pages and product marketing pages have moved to the [stackoverflow.co](https://stackoverflow.co/) domain, instead of sharing a domain with the Q&A website Stack Overflow. Correspondingly, the "About Us" link now points to this new domain as well.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange has changed its company name to Stack Overflow in September 2015, announcing it in [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/), so this explain why you see "Stack Overflow the company".

Now as for being hosted on stackoverflow.com itself, that's naturally because that is the largest and most dominant site in the network of sites, so it makes sense.

There is also [about page](https://stackexchange.com/about) in stackexchange.com itself, which essentially explains about the network of sites, so I am not sure why not  linking to that page on all sites except Stack Overflow.

Comment: Note – the pages about the company (rather than the Q&A site in particular) have since moved to the https://stackoverflow.co domain.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that the "About Us" can't be different for each Stack Exchange site, but would it make sense to link to something about Stack Exchange, rather than Stack Overflow?

No, since [Stack Overflow is the company name](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/). It is a little ambiguous, but Stack Overflow can refer to the site and to the brand / company name nowadays.