# Change link for about us to https://stackexchange.com/about

Tags: feature-request, footer

I'm talking about the `about us` link that bottom line has on every site i.e about us, tour, help etc.:

[image: screenshot]

Currently it links to https://stackoverflow.com/company/about but it should go to https://stackexchange.com/about. Though I think `help>>About Us` (Drop-down menu) should also link to https://stackexchange.com/about but it is mentioned `Learn about Stack Overflow the company` and being discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279837/260388).

So, I'm [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)ing to correct link for about us in the bottom bar. And also do for `help>>about us` if you consider suitable.

Note: We can add (currently missing I think) https://stackoverflow.com/company/about in https://stackexchange.com/about by providing link like About Stack Overflow the company.

Comment: Add tag for respected bar if available (I'm sure what is the bar I'm talking about called for adding/creating related tag)

Comment: Note – The corresponding link is now under the "Company" section of the footer, and points to https://stackoverflow.co (the [domain that the about-the-company pages moved to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415962/1478931)).